# How to keep the coloring in bash when using `sudo -i`?

Tags: command-line, bash, ps1

I have changed PS1 variable in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to

```
PS1="\n\[\033[0;37m\]\342\224\214\342\224\200\$(if [[ \$? == 0 ]]; then echo \"[\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[01;32m\]\342\234\223\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200\"; else echo \"[\[\033[0;32m\]\[\033[01;31m\]\342\234\227\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200\"; fi)[$(if [[ ${EUID} == 0 ]]; then echo '\[\033[0;31m\]\h'; else echo '\[\033[0;33m\]\u\[\033[0;37m\]@\[\033[0;96m\]\h'; fi)\[\033[0;37m\]]\342\224\200[\[\033[0;32m\]\w\[\033[0;37m\]]\n\[\033[0;37m\]\342\224\224\342\224\200\342\224\200\342\225\274 \[\033[0m\]"
```

Which works fine with all the commands. But when I run `sudo -i` command, PS1 value goes to the default. To get back the color scheme, I have to run `PS1=<same value>` manually. Any idea what might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Wow. Sexy. I stole it for my bash (:

Comment: I don't quite undertand the commands used here but I like it. The only problem is instead of showing 'root' as the name of the user it shows a question mark box, as if there is a missing character or something,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the `PS1` line to `/root/.bashrc`.

The reason why the color goes back to default is because when you do `sudo -i`, it "simulates" a root login, and in turn sources (applies) root's `.bashrc`, which brings the color back to the default. So adding the `PS1` line to root's `.bashrc` should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

I was going to add `PS1`, following the answer by Alaa Ali, and I've found the following lines:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=no
```

I've changed it to `force_color_prompt=yes`, then `exit`, login back, and voilà! Colors!

I'm on Ubuntu (disco), hope that this help. I think that it's better than PS1 because there's a lot of code that depends on this variable, I don't know exactly what's doing, but somebody has written it, I don't want to waste his/her time :-)